# cosmetic changes in .csv before downloading from javascript

Tags: javascript, json, excel, csv

I have below JS funciton to download .csv file from javascript, which is working as expected.

```
function downloadCSVFromJson(filename, arrayOfJson) {
    // convert JSON to CSV
    const replacer = (key, value) => value == null ? '' : value // specify how to handle null values here
    let header = Object.keys(arrayOfJson[0]);
    let csv = arrayOfJson.map(row => header.map(fieldName =>
        JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
    csv.unshift(header.join(','));
    csv = csv.join('\r\n');

    // Create link and download
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURIComponent(csv));
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

below is the screen shot of how data looks in excel if download using above method.

[image]

But is it possible to make it look like below from the javascript with filters on header and lock and freeze the header and first couple of columns?

[image]

In my defense I have spend a lot of time on google before posting this question but didn't get any documentation or blog post to do the same, could some one please suggest if this is possible from the javascript without using any third party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. CSV files can't store information on Excel filter/table structures.

Comment: is there any alternative to do the same?

Comment: You could export the file as .xlsx (they're just ZIP files with XML inside, and I bet there are libraries to write them anyway), where you can format an Excel table.